# laravel validation check if input value exists in emails or users

Tags: laravel

please I want know if there is any method to validate an input if exists in column email or username
without deal with code just validation system in laravel like

```
'username'=>'required|exists:App\Models\User,email OR exists:App\Models\User,username'
```

I want to make a 'LOST PASSWORD' like wordpress

wordpress lost password system ask the users for email or username  if exits it's okey if it's not display an error message

Comment: There's a list of available validations in the documentation. Take 15 seconds to look it over and you should find what you need. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Also, this is bad practice, as it advises attackers what is and is not a valid account on your system. Use Laravel's built-in authentication system to handle these kinds of things.

Comment: Yes, it's bad practice but you can use custom validation rule class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to check if the `username` exists as a `users.email` or as a `users.username`, you should make a [Custom Validation Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) - since the [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists) rule can't cover both of these. Something like this should work:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

use App\Models\User;

class EmailOrUsername implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return User::where(function($q) use($value) {
            $q->orWhere('email', $value)->orWhere('username', $value);
        })->count() > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Sorry, your credentials do not match our records.';
    }
}
```

When you need to use it, you do it like this:

```php
<?php

use App\Rules\EmailOrUsername;

$request->validate([
    'username' => ['required', 'string', new EmailOrUsername],
]);
```